# Why is postgres password authentication failing in deno?

Tags: postgresql, deno

I am able to connect fine from psql and node.js, but not from deno using [deno-postgres](https://deno-postgres.com/#/). Why is this?

I am running postgres 15 in docker using the official postgres:15 image. This is the [composed](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) service:

```yaml
db:
  image: postgres:15
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: foo
```

I can connect to it without any problem using psql

`psql postgres://postgres:foo@localhost:5432/postgres`

and node.js

```js
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client('postgres://postgres:foo@localhost:5432/postgres');
client.connect();
```

but from deno (1.29.2)

```js
import { Client } from 'https://deno.land/x/postgres@v0.16.1/mod.ts';
const client = new Client('postgres://postgres:foo@localhost:5432/postgres');
client.connect();
```

I get this in the deno log

> error: Uncaught (in promise) PostgresError: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
> throw new PostgresError(parseNoticeMessage(maybe_sasl_final));

And this in the db log

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

**Found 3 different solutions thanks to [spyrospal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163296/1859989)**

- [Upgrade the deno-postgres library](https://github.com/denodrivers/postgres/issues/182#issuecomment-767004796) to 0.17.0
- Downgrade to the postgres:13 image which [is configured to use md5 instead of scram-sha-256](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#postgres_host_auth_method)
- Provide an extra environment variable when initializing the docker container for image version 14+ ([POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html#id-1.9.5.3.6): "[--auth md5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html#id-1.9.5.3.6)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage seems correct.

You can verify the authentication error by inspecting the log of the `db` container. You should be able to see something like this:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Are you getting any more info from the logs?

The lib seems to have attempted a login using the scram-sha-256 authentication method. Use can see the configured auth methods by inspecting the contents of the [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

```
docker exec -it db cat /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

If the scram-sha-256 method is indeed enabled maybe changing to md5 can help.
Finally, if all fails then you can try to update to `v0.17.0` version of the
deno-postgres.

Comment: Yes, indeed getting `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`, and yes `scram-sha-256` looks to be enabled (last row of pg_hba.conf is `host all all all scram-sha-256`).

Can confirm the problem can be solved by either changing to a client supporting scram-sha-256 (e.g. bump deno-postgres to 0.17.0) or by changing the server to use md5 (either downgrade to v13 or adding `--auth md5` as an init arg)